# Is it possible to force return the Connection header from ASP.NET Core through IIS?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, http-headers, kestrel-http-server, response-headers

*Note: This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63345613/is-it-possible-to-force-return-the-connection-header-from-asp-net-core-through-a) but is about IIS, not Azure App Service on Linux.*

I have an API endpoint for uploading large files. The file should not be uploaded if authentication fails, if the filename is invalid, etc. We even accept a checksum and skip upload if the file already exists.

Unfortunately, Kestrel always drains the entire request body no matter what I do in user code (see [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/24732) for details). In other words, the user has to "upload" the whole file before getting the response, even if my code does not read the response body and returns an early error response. In that issue I received a tip that I could return a `Connection: close` header to avoid that. Unfortunately, while I receive the header in the response when debugging locally, I do not receive it when running in production through IIS. In other words, IIS seems to remove that header if it's present in the ASP.NET Core response.

Is there any way to force return a `Connection: close` header through IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could try to  disable allowKeepAlive for your asp.net core application.

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol allowKeepAlive="false" />
</system.webServer>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Disabling that makes IIS always send the `Connection: close` header regardless of what I do in code. That has performance implications. Is it possible to make that change only for a specific path? That would solve my problem.

Comment: @cmeeren Of course, you only have to add a <location> tag in your web.config. Then you can disable keep-alive for specific path. Like  <location path="folderA/a.aspx">
        <system.webServer>
            <httpProtocol allowKeepAlive="false" />
        </system.webServer>
    </location>

Comment: I tried setting `allowKeepAlive` to `false` (both location-specific and globally), and `Connection: close` is returned, but the entire request body is still read. So something else must be wrong. In any case, the question is answered.