# Is it possible to force return the Connection header from ASP.NET Core through Azure App Service on Linux

Tags: asp.net-core, http-headers, azure-web-app-service, kestrel-http-server, response-headers

*Note: This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63345548/is-it-possible-to-force-return-the-connection-header-from-asp-net-core-through-i) but is about Azure App Service on Linux, not IIS.*

I have an API endpoint for uploading large files. The file should not be uploaded if authentication fails, if the filename is invalid, etc. We even accept a checksum and skip upload if the file already exists.

Unfortunately, Kestrel always drains the entire request body no matter what I do in user code (see [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/24732) for details). In other words, the user has to "upload" the whole file before getting the response, even if my code does not read the response body and returns an early error response. In that issue I received a tip that I could return a `Connection: close` header to avoid that. Unfortunately, while I receive the header in the response when debugging locally, I do not receive it when running in production through Azure App Service on Linux. In other words, the Azure App Service on Linux environment seems to remove that header if it's present in the ASP.NET Core response.

Is there any way to force return a `Connection: close` header through Azure App Service on Linux?

Comment: I saw in github that this issue has been closed. You can post your solution to the problem, which can help more forum users, thank you.

Comment: The issue wasn't about about how to force the header through hosting software. The issue was resolved by telling me I should return a `Connection: close` header, but my problem is that I can't find a way to do it.